# Swift Package Manager - How to `Always Embed Swift Standard Libraries`?

Tags: swift, build, compiler-flags, swift-package-manager

We have CLI tool written in Swift for common usage (Android and iOS developers) on macOS.
Android developers without Xcode installation get the following error:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/libswiftCore.dylib
Referenced from: ~/git/myClITool/macosBin Reason: image not found
Abort trap: 6
```

We found that enabling `Always Embed Swift Standard Libraries` in Xcode would most likely help, but this CLI tool is exported with SPM, ignoring all Xcode settings.

How can I achieve this build behaviour using SwiftPM only?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the following commandline argument: `--static-swift-stdlib`

Example usage:
`swift build --static-swift-stdlib -c release`

This would have produced the output we were looking for. Unfortunately since Swift 5, this argument **no longer works** on macOS.

When used, SwiftPM throws the following warning:

> warning: Swift compiler no longer supports statically linking the
> Swift libraries. They're included in the OS by default starting with
> macOS Mojave 10.14.4 beta 3. For macOS Mojave 10.14.3 and earlier,
> there's an optional Swift library package that can be downloaded from
> "More Downloads" for Apple Developers at
> https://developer.apple.com/download/more/

Related Swift bugticket: https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-648